# Issue with for loop with sqlite data insertion

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, for-loop, syntax

I need to insert 5 rows where only one column values gets changed and remaining are same in all rows.

```
var Category1_fr ="one";
var Category2_fr ="one";
var Category3_fr ="one";
var Category4_fr ="one";
var Category5_fr ="one";

for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO testTable(Language, Standard, Category, QuestionID, SubmitText, HeaderText) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',[Language_fr,Standard_fr,Category"'+i+'"_fr,Question_fr,Submit_fr,Header_fr]);
     }
```

I am getting the syntax error. What is the correct syntax in java script for `Category'"+i+"'_fr` so that on each iterate I need to store all the `Category1_fr,Category2_fr,Category3_fr,Category4_fr,Category5_fr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to store the value as text in a variable and use it in the query like this :

```
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    var catFr = 'Category' + i + '_fr';
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO testTable(Language, Standard, Category, QuestionID, SubmitText, HeaderText) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',[Language_fr,Standard_fr,catFr,Question_fr,Submit_fr,Header_fr]);
}
```

Comment: Still I am getting error like "Uncaught Syntax error"

Comment: Are the different parameters (Language_fr, Standard_fr, ...) supposed to be text or they are variables declared sooner in your script ?

Comment: All the the variables. I have declared globally and initialized in other js file

Comment: Can you add the lines where the error gets thrown in your question. We need to know where is the syntax error.